# Block access on site via tools

Tags: java, php, http, authorization

We are running a file mirroring service and would like to know if it is possible to block indirect access to our site with jDownloader or similar downloading tools, To download a file user must visit via browser, jDownloader is faking user-agent and also it can break cookie methods so its not possible to block access with that way, any suggestion please?

Best Regards

Comment: Make sure people can only download after registration?

Comment: thanks but we cant as its a file mirroring site not actual file host. we can loos traffic if we require user to register.

Comment: Maybe with a cookie? I don't know if those tools store cookies.

Comment: not possible with cookies they are storing cookies info as well.

Comment: sorry but jDownloader also have captcha breaking functionalists.It can provide captcha to user without visiting on site so he can manually enter captcha or use 3rd party tools.

Comment: how about hotlink protection? Use secret/sessions keys?

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to set a cookie on the site and use .htaccess to check for that cookie for downloads. Something along the lines:

```
RewriteCond [is download file]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_COOKIE} lang=([^;]+) [NC]
RewriteRule .* - [R=404]
```

Comment: Since jDownloader is also storing cookies, you would have to add a mechanism that sets proper cookies only for humans (captcha or some behaviour monitoring or javascript client side generated cookies). Maybe https://panopticlick.eff.org/ could come in handy?

Comment: Thanks but as i mentioned above cookies,captchas are not helpful.